# Why do the md5 hashes of two tarballs of the same file differ?

Tags: linux, hash, compression, md5, tar

I can run:

```
echo "asdf" > testfile
tar czf a.tar.gz testfile
tar czf b.tar.gz testfile
md5sum *.tar.gz
```

and it turns out that `a.tar.gz` and `b.tar.gz` have different md5 hashes. It's true that they're different, which `diff -u a.tar.gz b.tar.gz` confirms.

What additional flags do I need to pass in to `tar` so that its output is consistent over time with the same input?

Comment: The gzip header contains the modification time of the original file. When the input comes from a stream rather than compressing a file, it uses the current time.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks. Do you know how to make this not happen?

Comment: I can't think of a good way. I was going to post an answer where you make an uncompressed tarball, copy it with the `-p` option to preserve `mtime`, and then compress each of them. But the problem there is that `gzip` also puts the input filename into the file, and the filenames will be different.

Comment: Why don't you compare the checksums of the uncompressed file?

Comment: `zcat a.tar.gz | md5sum` and `zcat b.tar.gz | md5sum`

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer to Barmars answer please. His is correct and should be in first position.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`tar czf outfile infiles` is equivalent to

```
tar cf - infiles | gzip > outfile
```

The reason the files are different is because `gzip` puts its input filename and modification time into the compressed file. When the input is a pipe, it uses an empty string as the filename and the current time as the modification time.

But it also has a `--no-name` option, which tells it not to put the name and timestamp into the file. So if you write the expanded command explicitly, instead of using the `-z` option to `tar`, you can make use of this option.

```
tar cf - testfile | gzip --no-name > a.tar.gz
tar cf - testfile | gzip --no-name > b.tar.gz
```

I tested this on OS X 10.6.8 and it works.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.

Comment: Should I delete my post so yours goes to the top?

Comment: That's fine with me.

Comment: I just tried to delete it but because it has an accepted answer flag I wasn't able to. I'm going to ask to OP to accept yours instead.

Comment: @Harry There are a bunch of MSE questions about what to do in situations like this, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/what-happens-when-an-accepted-answer-is-wrong-but-the-op-is-gone. The best recommendation seems to be to downvote the wrong answer so the right one floats to the top, so I've downvoted yours.

Comment: I've flagged mine for moderator attention ie either delete it or remove the accepted flag.

Comment: I just noticed that. @ElizabethLin could though.

Comment: I've accepted it, sorry, haven't been at my computer for a while.

Comment: @ElizabethLin Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS:

In `man tar` we can look at `--options` section and there we will find `!timestamp` option, which will exclude timestamp from our gzip archive. Usage:

```sh
tar --options '!timestamp' -cvzf archive.tgz filename
```

It will produce same md5 sum for same files with same names