# Why two results of 'tar cvf' of a same project not matched?

Tags: md5, tar

I have a go project names hello which contains only a `main.go` source file.

I use `go build` to get an executable called `hello`, then `md5sum hello` to get its md5:`9d51bcdbddd40320ba3057f91952865e`. Then I use `tar cvf hello.tar hello` to get `hello.tar` and calculate its md5:`63fda573908ec8c1bfa58ac46419efbe`.

Next, I `rm hello hello.tar` and redo the things above:

`hello` md5: 9d51bcdbddd40320ba3057f91952865e (still the same)

`hello.tar` md5: 880dea1e12e5c69b24b83cf13db6606b (changed)

I'v already learned that if I use `tar czf` command, the md5 will surely change because of the timestamps in the archives are changed. But why `tar cf` also changes the md5?

refer: [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464358/why-do-the-md5-hashes-of-two-tarballs-of-the-same-file-differ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get hash of `hello` it get the content and calculate the hash.

But when you get `hello.tar` it include beside the `hello` file kind of header which include variables like modification time of file `hello`. And those timestamps change the content (and hash) of `hello.tar`

For reference of the `tar` header you can check [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html).